# Sourcetree set HEAD to origin/master

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to make the HEAD branch with comment "done" the origin/master branch or master branch. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: well now I lost it by double clicking on origin/master. How do I undo that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal in the project directory (there is a button on the SourceTree toolbar that does this) and run:

```
git reflog
```

It shows the recent positions of the `HEAD` (the current branch or commit). Yours should start with:

```
***** HEAD@{0} checkout: moving from xxxxx to master
```

where `xxxxx` is a commit hash. It is the hash of the commit you were previously on (shown in the image with commit message "done").

You can check this by running:

```
git log -n 1 xxxxx
```

(replace `xxxxx` in the command above with the actual hash).

If it is, indeed, the commit you need then you can run:

```
git checkout -B master xxxxx
```

to make the `master` branch point to the commit with the message "done".

Read more about [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) and [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Don't double-click rows in SourceTree; it will try to checkout the commit you double-click and you'll end up in a [detached `HEAD`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head) state.

Comment: yea I accidentally double clicked it and now that HEAD commit is gone. Can I undo it somehow? I did force push on it before I doubled clicked but I can't seem to get it back.

Comment: Have you tried the answer? I wrote it after you posted this info in a comment on the question. The answer handles this scenario.

Comment: yes I did. FIXED EVERYTHING! Thank you! Almost lost 5 hours of work. You're a godsend!